# Default output file type when exporting to CAD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, dxf

The default format for export format for ArcGIS 10.1 is DWG_2010. Is there any way to change it to another format? In my case I need it to DXF_2000.
The only known way to export to cad for me is right click on the geodatabase -> data -> export to cad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the ArcGIS CAD export tool interface, the default is the latest release of AutoCAD supported by the ArcGIS version you used to export. Can't make a preferred option stick. With a script or model builder, your output options are permanent, unless changed and therefore preferred option can be made to stick.

Comment: Then I gues I should start learning how to code/script.

Comment: @lonescu take a look at modelbuilder as ZrSiO4 suggests. You dont need any coding experience for that

Answer (score 2):

From the [Help file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Export_To_CAD/00120000001n000000/) for this tool, you need only change the parameter Output_Type to *DXF_R2000*.

Comment: Call me ignorant , but by doing so , will only change the output type for the curent export and any future exports will be DWG_2010. Or I might be blind today and cant see the obvios.

Comment: You do not describe in your post how you are running this tool; stand alone or as part of a model or a script? So no one can help you identify why it is defaulting back to DWG_2010. You need edit your question and explain what your workflow is for anyone to have a guess at why it is not behaving.